# Malloc implementation with C

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to implement Malloc manually in a C project.
Here is my code:

```
void *Mem_Alloc(int size) {
    struct Node *p, *prevp = head;

    if (fitPolicy == P_BESTFIT) {

    }

    if (fitPolicy == P_FIRSTFIT) {
        for (p = prevp->next; ;prevp = p, p = p->next) {
            if (p->size >= size) {
                if (p->size == size)
                    prevp->next = p->next;
                else {
                    p->size -= size;
                    p += p->size;
                    // p->size = size;
                }
                head = prevp;
                return (void *)(p+1);
            }
            if (p == head) {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    if (fitPolicy == P_WORSTFIT) {

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Basically, I call `mmap` in another method called `Mem_Init`; then, the returned memory map is pointed to by the variable `head`.
I always get a segmentation fault on the commented part in the middle of `Mem_Alloc`. I do not know why. Could you guys help me with this? Some hints?

Comment: ughoavgfhw gives the right direction, and the commented line of size is not correct. it should be `p->size = the_size_left_in_the_block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ughoavgfhw has the right direction, but casting lvalue is not appropriate.

You can use:

```
void * tmp_p = (void *)p;
tmp_p += p->size;
p = (struct Node *)tmp_p;
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on `void*` is a GCC extension (undefined behaviour per the standard). For portability, use `char*`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used the casting to char method.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to tell for sure, but this is most likely because you are expecting `p += p->size` to increment `p` by `p->size` bytes. In reality, this would increment it by `p->size` times the size of `*p`. If the size you are trying to allocate is less than half the size of the memory you have available, this would move the pointer past the end even if `*p` is only 2 bytes.

To fix this, you should cast your pointer to a character pointer for the addition.

```
((char*)p) += p->size;
```